# CMake: How to set different variable value for different build configuration?

Tags: cmake

In my project I need to include different files for different build configurations and thus far I've been unable to find a way to do it via CMake.

My build command looks the following way:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Debug2017;Debug2018;Debug2019;Release2017;Release2018;Release2019 -G"Visual Studio 14 2015" #and so on
```

In my CMakeLists.txt I want to have something that looks like:

```
if ($<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>: )
    set (MAYA_DIRECTORY "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017" )>
endif()
if ($<$<CONFIG:Debug2018>: )
    set (MAYA_DIRECTORY "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018" )>
endif()
#and so on; obviously script above don't work. I posted it just as an example of what I want to achieve
```

variable MAYA_DIRECTORY is used later on to set different other variables that are used for include_directories(…) and link_directories(…) calls.

If there is a way to do this by something other than generator expressions that would also work.

Thanks!

Comment: If multiple configurations are provided, which folder do you want `MAYA_DIRECTORY` to be set to? Is the idea that only *one* configuration is passed via `-DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` at a time?

Comment: Idea is that multiple configurations are provided and we want to have different paths set for different configuration. The thing is that Maya have different devkit for different versions, thus when Debug2017 is chosen I need to include files from Maya2017 devkit, when Debug2018 then from Maya2018 devkit and so on. Currently I have project file set up manually and I have different paths for different configurations. I want to have similar behavior

Comment: Your pseudo code appears to overwrite the contents of `MAYA_DIRECTORY` with each configuration that is encountered. Do you want `MAYA_DIRECTORY` to contain a *list* of directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. It is possible for single config generators to use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` but that strategy fails for for multi-config generators like Visual Studio.  This is mixing up what happens at configuration time and build time.  The active configuration happens at build time.

Therefore you need a separate `MAYA_DIRECTORY` for each build config.  Then you need to include each Maya into the build (I'm guessing they are external projects or something).  Then you need to use a generator expressions to pick which Maya you want to use in the executable.

It would be something like this.

```
target_include_directories(myApp PRIVATE
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug2016>:${MAYA_2016_INCS}>
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:${MAYA_2017_INCS}> )

target_link_libraries(myApp PRIVATE
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug2016>:${MAYA_2016_LIBS}>
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:${MAYA_2017_LIBS} )
```

FYI, If you are creating multiple configuration types you need to seed them properly. That is make sure you create a `*_Debug2017` with the debug flags and so on.

Comment: Yes, Maya is an application that I am making plug-ins for. There are different versions of it (2019, 2018, 2017, etc...) and each of them have different dev kit (different libs and headers) thus I need to link to different libs and include different headers as well.

Comment: @DmitriiMotorygin Then it's pretty simple.  You just use generator expressions in the `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries`.